Help Needed: Mazda 6 (2008) Gear Issue in Hot Weather and Traffic - Any Advice?
I’m seeking advice on a frustrating issue I’m experiencing with my 2008 Mazda 6, which has about 115,000 miles on it. The car generally drives perfectly, but I'm encountering a persistent problem with the gearbox in specific conditions.
Symptoms: When driving in very hot weather or in stop-and-start traffic, I find it nearly impossible to engage 1st and reverse gears. This problem does not occur when the car is cold; the gears engage smoothly when I first start driving and for the first few miles.
Progression: The difficulty in shifting into 1st and reverse gears worsens as the car gets hotter and more gear changes are made. Even if I turn off the engine, 1st and reverse remain impossible to engage until the car has cooled down for about an hour.
Temporary Workaround: I can often engage 1st gear by pushing the gear selector to where it is 'waiting' to shift into first as the slows to a stop - it will slip into place with no extra effort at maybe 2-3 miles per hour. However, if the car stops completely, I have to start it in 2nd gear (which also becomes more difficult but not impossible to engage.)
Attempted Fix: I’ve already had the gearbox oil replaced, but unfortunately, it hasn’t made any difference. Also, there is no grinding when I shift into any gears.
Would appreciate any insights or suggestions.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
